# Python: OpenCV VideoCapture captures green and purple from 4K Camera. How to access high MP cameras using OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

I am using 4K Camera and I am trying to access it using OpenCV. I am getting green and purple colors and nothing else. When I connect the camera directly to my computer, it works just fine.

This is the code I am running:

```
import cv2 as cv

cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
  _, frame = cap.read()
  
  cv.imshow("frame", frame)
  if cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break

cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is the frame I a getting:
[Green/Purple pixels only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iae94.png)

This is the details of my camera: [4K UVC Camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZSHA.png)

Comment: The pink and green shades _maybe hint_ at a conversion problem from some YUV colorspace to BGR/RGB. Maybe you can trying converting the frame before displaying it. Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60729170/python-opencv-converting-planar-yuv-420-image-to-rgb-yuv-array-format

Comment: Hello @stateMachine, I checked the link and was able to split the channels and convert them separately. Still, I am wondering why I am only seeing bars of green and pink. Could this be caused by the camera having high MegaPixels?